# jenkins shared environment between child projects

Tags: jenkins

I create a Folder project (ProjectA). Inside this project, I add multiple child freestyle and pipeline projects. The project structure as below.

```
ProjectA
    |-- freestyle_project_1
    |-- freestyle_project_2
    |-- pipleline_project_1
    |-- pipleline_project_2
```

Question: I want to define a set of environment variables at ProjectA level. All the child projects use them directly in jekinsfile or shell command. How to achieve this?

Comment: Is same environment variables are to be used for all projects ?

Comment: Not all projects of the whole jenkins cluster. Just for the child projects of ONE folder.